# How can I bridge two different networks over wifi?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, port-forwarding, dd-wrt

Consider the following hardware scenario:

- Device: this is the device from which I want to obtain data.  When it is powered on, it creates a wifi network whose SSID/network key are fixed and cannot be changed.  When I join the network with a computer or phone, I will be assigned IP address 192.168.1.2.  Device A will ALWAYS be 192.168.1.1 and I can get the data by opening a socket to port 5000, 192.168.1.1.  The data will come at a rate of 500 kilobytes per second.
- Wifi-only tablet: I want to use the tablet to obtain data from the device, BUT I want the tablet to be on my home network (192.168.0.x) at the same time, so it can have internet.  So it cannot directly connect to the device, otherwise it will have no internet.
- Computer (Ethernet + wifi): I am using this as a bridge.  The computer uses its wifi card to join the wifi network created by the device, and is on my home network with Ethernet.  I have the computer listen on port 5000 on its 192.168.0 interface, and forward it to port 5000 on its 192.168.1 interface, using the instructions found at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11525703/port-forwarding-in-windows.

This solution works, however, the data rate from the device is no longer 500 kilobytes per second, it is now 250 kilobytes per second and too slow.  What am I doing wrong?  Is there any special hardware I can buy, or perhaps can I use a DD-WRT router to bridge and get maximum speed?

Comment: So the device has it's own broadcast domain and does DHCP? what is the netmask of the subnet? Is it acting in an isolated AP mode and giving every device that connects to it simultaneously 192.168.1.2 or can only 1 device be connected at a time? Seems like it is being used outside of design, what is this device? That aside, this would likely require 2 pieces of equipment, a wireless bridge and a more sophisticated router like an Asus RT-N66U or something similar running DD-WRT or Open-WRT to handle routing of multiple subnets.

Comment: The device is a camera with unchangeable SSID/key and can only accept one client at a time (and that client will be on the 192.168.1.x) subnet.  I need my 192.168.0.x-subnetted computer to be able to talk to it without leaving the 192.168.0.x LAN.  I have a spare router that has DD-WRT on it but I am unsure of how to use DD-WRT to link the two together.  The DD-WRT router have to get an IP on 192.168.1.x wirelessly and 192.168.0.x wired and somehow be configured to forward its 192.168.0.x traffic to the device.

Comment: There is no way to reconfigure the camera? To be honest, it might be easier to just replace the camera to one that can actually be a client since you are willing to replace hardware... Otherwise it will be tricky if the camera has to be the "host", you would have to use a DD-WRT router and a bridge device, connect to the DD-WRT's WAN port and connect the lans together, using the DD-WRT as a second gateway. Still might not work, depends how strict the security is on the camera

Answer (score 0):

I actually ended up solving this, hope it is helpful for someone in the future: DD-WRT must be set in client mode, so it can join the AP.

Then, you need to disable the DHCP server on DD-WRT and instead set the commands up to have DD-WRT be a DHCP client on the LAN:

Wireless->Basic Settings->Wireless Mode: Client

Disable DHCP Server (Setup->Basic Setup->DHCP Server:  Disable)

Administration->Commands (save as startup script):

```
ln -s /sbin/rc /tmp/udhcpc
/usr/sbin/udhcpc -i br0 -p /var/run/udhcpc.pid -s /tmp/udhcpc -H `nvram get router_name`
route add default gw `nvram get wan_gateway`
nvram set wds_watchdog_ips="`nvram get wan_gateway`"

# Config DNS
/bin/cat /etc/resolv.conf | /bin/grep -v nameserver > /tmp/resolv.conf
/bin/echo nameserver `nvram get wan_get_dns` >> /tmp/resolv.conf
/bin/cp /tmp/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf
```

(Reference: http://www.netguy.org/wordpress/?p=242)

And my speed issue was apparently caused by wifi channel interference, so moving to another channel fixed the problem.